# Retrieve data from google spreadsheets using ajax get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, google-sheets

I was trying this code to get the data in a google spreadsheet which I have already published.Also I have choosen the option 'any one can edit' in share properties of the spreadsheet.I gave the right url...But still getting error. Hope some one can help me with this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("working");
            $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
                console.log("click working");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fZM17gx-wo7PQIxHGe6kM4Wv1f2a-5sGhcnjGTCf5Bk/pubhtml",
                    data: "task=addNewInfo&" + $('#regForm').serialize(),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        alert(data);
                        alert(data.ip);
                    },
                    error: function (xqhr, error, exception) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });

                });
                             
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="btnsubmit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have several issues. Firstly if you run the snippet you'll see an error: `Unexpected token }`. This is because you have one too many  `});` in your code. Remove it. Secondly, you've included two versions of jQuery. One of which, 1.4.3, is over 7 years out of date. Remove that too. Once that's done the request is made, however it fails because the response from the request is HTML, not JSON as you've told jQuery that it will be. You need to change the logic to work with that HTML.

Comment: You have one `});` to much. Delete one and try again.

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan.....Ihave made the changes you have pointed. But still getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sheetrock/1.1.4/dist/sheetrock.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fZM17gx-wo7PQIxHGe6kM4Wv1f2a-5sGhcnjGTCf5Bk/edit#gid=0'; 
            $('#tab').sheetrock({
                url: mySpreadsheet
            });
            $('tab tr td').each(function () {

                                 
                });
                });

    </script>
    <table id="tab" style="display: none;"></table>
</body>
</html>
```